# Improving My Python Solution for CSV Name Parsing: lastname, firstname to firstname lastname

Tags: python, csv

I had to implement a real-world solution in Python for a client having trouble with a tricky CSV file. A column labeled **Contacts** contained names written as `lastname, firstname` in each cell. He needed them to be `firstname lastname` in each cell.

My solution worked but it reflects how new I am to coding. I needed to split the names on the `,` but since a CSV sees each row as a `list` I wasn't able to use `split` -- hence, the conversion of each row to a string first.

What is a more efficient way to handle this?

Thanks for all the input!

```
import csv

with open('names_to_process.csv', 'r') as in_file:
    in_data = csv.reader(in_file)

    with open('newnames.csv', 'w') as out_csv:
        out_data = csv.writer(out_csv)

        for row in in_data:
            name_string = ''.join(row) #converts each field from lst to str
            reversed_name = name_string.split(',') #.split now that its a str

            lname = ' ' + reversed_name[0] + "\n"
            fullname = reversed_name[1].lstrip() + lname

            out_csv.write(fullname)
```

Comment: If your code works without any problems, a better place to ask could be [codereview.se]. Check their guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your data only ever has two columns, the following approach is a bit simpler:

```
import csv

with open('names_to_process.csv', 'rb') as in_file, open('newnames.csv', 'wb') as out_file:
    in_csv = csv.reader(in_file)
    out_csv = csv.writer(out_file)

    for last_name, first_name in in_csv:
        out_csv.writerow(["{} {}".format(first_name, last_name)])
```

For example, a file containing:

```
flintstone,fred
rubble,barney
```

Would produce:

```
fred flintstone
barney rubble
```

This assumes you are using Python 2.x, if you are using Python 3.x, you will need to modify it to:

```
with open('names_to_process.csv', 'r', newline='') as in_file, open('newnames.csv', 'w', newline='') as out_file:
```

Comment: Thanks, Martin. I'm excited to use shared knowledge to improve and I appreciate your response! Also, his original CSV file had many columns. I simply didn't have the skills to deal with it. I pulled out the column with the names and fed that through my script then pasted the corrected names back into his master file.

Comment: You're welcome! Don't forget to click on the grey tick under the up/down buttons to select the answers as the accepted solution.

Comment: I did :). Votes cast by those with 15 reputation or less don't show but are recorded.

Comment: Thanks, you should still click the grey tick though underneath. It will appear green after you click on it. You should then get the scholar badge.

Comment: Not a problem, you'd be surprised just how many don't figure out that the tick is actually a button.